# Is the space between 2 bars or balusters of a gate called a "crack" or "gap"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

Is the space between 2 bars or balusters of a gate called a "**crack**" or "**gap**" (see the picture)

For example, "*the dog managed to squeeze through the gap/crack of the gate*"

I heard some native speakers say "**crack**" not "**gap**".

Comment: I’d use “gap” normally, but in this context I would use “crack” because I’m surprised the dog managed to squeeze through such a small gap.

Comment: **Crack** does not sound appropriate to me because a *crack* is usually something irregular and unnatural ([like this](https://countercurrents.org/2020/09/a-crack-in-the-earth/)), not a planned space between things.

Comment: I agree with @stangdon. A crack is normally a sign of damage, not a space that is part of the design of something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would not use "crack" unless the opening was *extremely* small (maximum 1-2cm) and, ideally, not man-made. Based on the picture I would say the dog squeezed between the **gap** or **space** between the slats.